# Can you identify this strange powdery stuff on my floor joists?

Tags: wood, termite

I am not sure if this substance has always been there and I simply haven't noticed it until recently, or if it has started appear recently.

The area these photos were taken in previously had a serious mouse infestation (severe enough to remove all drywall and insulation).

The substance (at least the parts that I touched) crumbles to the touch. It almost reminds me of wood filler before it quite sets.

I do not see any insects, or any insect paths in the wood. I do not see any indication that the wood itself is damaged (so far..). The third picture is of the underside of the plywood for the floor above - those are nails coming down through it, not damaged wood.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The joists seem to have had paint slapped on them, probably a paint job or just using a bit of paint up.  The plywood is hard to tell if it was used as floor protection during a paint job or there is some fungus/mold on it   Having some of it tested is the only way to tell if fungus/mold, but there are simple ways to kill it.

Comment: Looks like the plywood and framing were walked on (and/or piled) in muddy conditions at the time of building, and never cleaned. Is there clay soil or subsoil around your house?

Comment: @Ecnerwal, hmm yes, there is a lot of clay here. It could well be dirt that was just never cleaned.

Comment: @crip659, it does look like a bit like paint splashes, but I think the mud theory fits better - I went down and was able to brush some of it away. It's totally dry as well.

Comment: To me this looks like paint or more likely drywall compound (i.e. "mud") that got dropped or spilled and then walked over.  I'd scrape it off and sweep up the mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a light-colored clay dating from when the construction materials were piled and walked over before being installed.

It's not unusual for lumber products to get dirty, and it's a rare crew that will bother to clean them where not absolutely required. And knowing a few ceramists well, and dabbling myself, it does look much like dried clay on wood looks.

Comment: Yeah, my attic trusses still have mud on them. :)